# nltk lemmatizer doesn't know what to do with the word Americans

Tags: python, nltk, lemmatization

Ran the following:

```
from nltk import WordNetLemmatizer as wnl
wnl().lemmatize("American")
wnl().lemmatize("Americans")
```

Both of which simply return their argument. I would like Americans to reduce down to American. Anybody have any idea how to make this happen?

I assumed I'd have to modify whatever internal dictionary the lemmatizer is using. Is this correct? Anybody know a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: it would seem more natural to me if they both were lemmatized to `America`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the word to lower case before giving it to the lemmatizer, and restore the case afterwards.

I have used this code in the past:

```
word = 'Americans'
lemmatized = wnl().lemmatize(word.lower())
if word.istitle():
    word = lemmatized.capitalize()
else:
    word = lemmatized
# word = 'American'
```

This assumes that there is no case of multiple upper case letters in a word (like "MySpace"), which was true for my case that time. I think this is generally true, since words with multiple uppercase letters tend to be a proper noun, and hence there is usually no need to lemmatize them.

If you're concerned with all UPPERCASE word, you can include that case also:

```
word = 'AMERICANS'
lemmatized = wnl().lemmatize(word.lower())
if word.istitle():
    word = lemmatized.capitalize()
elif word.upper()==word:
    word = lemmatized.upper()
else:
    word = lemmatized
# word = 'AMERICAN'
```

Answer (score 5):

Apparently case matters to WordNet, but you can also use PorterStemmer.

```
>>> wnl().lemmatize('americans')
'american'
>>> from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer as ps
>>> ps().stem('Americans')
'American'
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't want to use stemmer because I need these to be presentable dictionary words for the most part (American is in a paragraph of text). I think the issue is that American can be either an adjective or a noun- e.g. 'the American went to market' vs. 'He went to the American market'. I guess I'm saying I don't think they're all part of the same lexeme anymore.